# Why an APK won't be signed?

Tags: android, ant, apk, code-signing, private-key

I have strange situation, where the unsigned version is built... but not the signed APK!

Here is some info about this:

*** I use ant, not eclipse.**

- I created the store key in command line by running the following:

  keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\my.keystore -alias my_alias.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

This placed the keystore in C:\

Now, to sign the apk I use the following command (during the build process):

```
jarsigner -storepass password -verbose -keystore "C:\Android-Enviroment\my.keystore" -signedjar "C:\Documents and Settings\O\Desktop\Project\bin\project-signed.apk" "C:\Documents and Settings\O\Desktop\Project\bin\Project-release-unsigned.apk" my_alias.keystore -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA
```

This cause *ONLY* the unsigned apk to build: **Project-release-unsigned.apk**
*without* the Project-signed.apk

So... the questions:

1- Is there is anything wrong of creating the key and/or building the sources?

2- How to debug this? I mean how do I know why the generated key isn't working?!

I'm beginner, so may be the answer is so obvious but I really couldn't figure it out!

Thanks for your help...

Comment: have you tried doing a clean before you build?

Comment: @Blaine what do you mean by clean? sorry if that's so obvious, I'm really just starting :)

Comment: Go to Projects > clean. Android has files that are automatically generated, and this will regenerate those files.

Comment: @Blaine I'm using ANT not eclipse, Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Blaine your suggestion was the right thing to do :)
I manually cleaned all the files after previous builds... and then ran the command again... 

everything went very well, and the apk was signed successfully. If you repeat your comment as an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks for your suggestion, thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you clean your project before you try and sign with a new type of key.

To do this you go to Projects > Clean.

Then rebuild.

Comment: That nailed it down... once I cleaned the sources, it was signing without issues. Thanks.